# Find $7^{1/2}$, $3^{1/2}$, and $1^{1/3}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find $7^{1/2}$, $3^{1/2}$, and $1^{1/3}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$

I couldn't think of a quick and clever way to answer this, so I calculated every element is $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ squared and cubed. I got that $7^{1/2}$ doesn't exist, $3^{1/2}$ equals 5 and 6, and $1^{1/3}$ only equals 1.

Are my answers correct and is there a better way to answer this question?

Comment: Well, since $3$ does not divide $11-1=10$ every element has a unique cube root.  Since $1^3=1$, that must be the only one.

Comment: @lulu ok, I remember a theorem like that. But by that logic, 7 should have 2 square roots right? Or am I misremembering the theorem?

Comment: I would work it backwards and find $a^2$ and $a^3$ for each element.  It may not be elegant but it is effective.

Comment: @DougM Thats what I did, but I didn't get a square root of 7 and the way the question is phrased makes me think there should be one.

Comment: If the set of $\mathbb Z_{11} = \{0,\pm 1, \pm2, \pm 3, \pm 4, \pm 5\}$  when we square those elements, the positive and the negative values map to the same number.  So, half the elements in $\mathbb Z_{11}$ have 2 square roots and half have none.

Comment: There is not square root of $\;7\;$ in $\;\Bbb F_{11}\;$ . Have you studied quadratic residues, quadratic reciprocity and stuff?

Comment: No...since $2$ does divide $10$ that means that some numbers have two square roots and some have none.

Comment: Technically, $\pm 5$ is only a square root of $3$ in $\mathbb Z/11 \mathbb Z$. In $\mathbb Z_{11}$, the square roots of $3$ are $\pm \dots 5AA29735_{11}$.

Comment: The numbers with square roots must be $2k + 1$ more than the previous so: $1, 1+3=4, 4+5=9, 9+7=5,4+9=3;3+11=3; 3+2 = 5;5+4=9;9+6=4;4+7 = 0$.  Which... admittedly isnt any easier but it makes $7$ not appearing less surprising.

Comment: @MishaLavrov why is 3 a square root in $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ and not $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$?

Comment: I'm being nitpicky about notation. $\mathbb Z_{11}$ *can* mean the integers modulo $11$, but it also often means the $11$-adic integers, especially when dealing with the existence of roots to polynomial equations. So we often write $\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z/(11)$ to denote the integers modulo $11$. You do not actually have to worry about this.

Comment: @MishaLavrov actually I'm concerned about this because this assignment asked me to find all the quadratic residues in $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ then later asked me to calculate all the quadratic residues in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$, and I thought it was as simple as 0 is not in the first but is in the second. Now I'm second guessing that answer.

Comment: You'd know to think about the $p$-adic integers if the assignment were related to them; they're not going to come at you by surprise. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by the notation $\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z_{11}$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I meant $\mathbb{Z}/{11\mathbb{Z}}$ I typed it wrong the first time and lazily copied it each time after without noticing my mistake. Actually, its a bigger mistake than that even, because I meant  $(\mathbb{Z}/{11\mathbb{Z}})^*$ which in my class denotes the elements in $\mathbb{Z}/{11\mathbb{Z}}$ that are co-prime with 11

Answer (score 1):

For $1^{1/3}$, note that $x \mapsto x^3$ is a bijection in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ because $\gcd(3,10)=1$. Since $1 \mapsto 1$, that's the only solution.

No so for $x \mapsto x^2$. There is probably no better way than finding all squares. You only need to compute the squares of $0,1,2,3,4,5$ because $(-x)^2=x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$1^3$, for solve this we have find the solutions a the equation
$$u^3\cong 1 \text{ mod }11$$
And $u^3-1=(u-1)(u^2+u+1),$ then $u-1=0$ or $u^2+u+1=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11},$ then
since $2$ not divide $11,$ we can factor the second using the usual formula
$$u=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{(1-4)}}{2}=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt 8}{2},$$ but $x^2=8$ has not solution simple inspection 
so the unique solution to $u^3=1$ is $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$